# EF is reinserting Entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have this code

```
            DivisionService divService = new DivisionService();
            Division div = divService.FindById(10); 
            Counter c = new Counter(div);

            unitOfWork.CounterRepository.Add(c);
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

This code is supposed to add a new `Counter` and not to add a new `Division` since the division is retrieved from the database, but what happens is that it adds both. Any idea what could be the problem?

EDIT

Below is the class `Counter`

```
public class Counter : BaseCounter
{

    Division division;

    private Counter()
    {

    }

    public Counter(Division division)
    {
        this.division = division;
    }

    public Division Division
    {
        get
        {
            return division;
        }
        private set
        {
            division = value;
        }
    }

    public override string GetNumber()
    {
        return number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is also the `BaseCounterRepository` that the `CounterRepository` and `CounterService` wraps

```
public abstract class BaseCounterRepository<T> where T : BaseCounter
{

    protected MyContext context;

    public BaseCounterRepository()
    {
        this.context = new MyContext();
    }

    public BaseCounterRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public virtual T FindById(int id)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        try
        {
            result = (T)context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle execption
        }

        return result;
    }

    public virtual T Add(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            T result = context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle execption
        }
    }

    public virtual void DeleteById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            T entity = context.Set<T>().Find(id);
            context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle execption
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show us your constructor of `Counter`?

Comment: here you are...

Comment: If you do not want to save division, do not provide it to the counter model. One of the reason why you should keep data access related models keep separate from business layer

Comment: @MatthiasBurger that was me who posted this question, and I choose independent association based on my understanding of article number 2 in the answer.

Comment: @Fabio it is a matter of business requirement, I can't construct a Counter with a Division.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003345/how-can-i-prevent-ef-from-inserting-an-object-that-already-exists-in-the-db-when) inspired me with the answer , it turned out that I was using different `UnitOfWork` (consequently `DBContext`) per `Service` class, that's why the `Division` from the `DivisionService` class looked new to the `CounterService` class and its `DBContext` and thus got reinserted.